# Putting a Login screen in one of the intro slides for flutter

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I currently have two dart files. One contains code for my intro slides part of my app (very similar to https://flutterappdev.com/2019/01/24/simple-and-configurable-app-introduction-slider-for-flutter/ the default config example).

In my other, I have my login screen (similar to https://github.com/Ethiel97/flutter_login_ui/blob/master/lib/main.dart). Is there any way for my slide 3 to contain my login screen?

I am quite new to app development and unsure if this is possible, if I'm able to connect two dart files, or if I'm not even supposed to have two dart files! Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Please let me know if my code is needed, though my two dart files are very similar to "class _MyHomePageState extends State" part of the code in the links above as I am just testing implementations out :)

Comment: No, you can't using that package. You can make it manually.

Comment: @Abhay Koradiya Oh do you mean manually make the intro slides? Also, in this case, there is a "Done" button for the intro slides, is it possible to code is so that if I press "Done" it redirects me to my Login screen?

Comment: yes it is possible to open login screen with done button

Comment: I'll look into it then! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `intro_views_flutter 2.8.0` to include any widget in the slides as your login page is also a widget.You can see [the example here](https://pub.dev/packages/intro_views_flutter#-example-tab-).The example given here is super easy and hope it'll help you.

Comment: Oh wow that's neat! Do you happen to know if there any way to make an image take up the whole screen instead of just having a small image in the center (my other version was able to do this)? I'm trying do the BoxFit.cover option but the image seems to be small still.

Comment: You can set a container with the whole screen and set it's decoration a image